# SQL combine two queries result into one dataset

Tags: sql-server, report, builder

I am trying to combine two SQL queries the first is

```
SELECT 
    EAC.Person.FirstName, 
    EAC.Person.Id,
    EAC.Person.LastName, 
    EAC.Person.EmployeeId, 
    EAC.Person.IsDeleted, 
    Controller.Cards.SiteCode, 
    Controller.Cards.CardCode, 
    Controller.Cards.ActivationDate, 
    Controller.Cards.ExpirationDate, 
    Controller.Cards.Status, 
    EAC.[Group].Name
FROM         
    EAC.Person 
INNER JOIN 
    Controller.Cards ON EAC.Person.Id = Controller.Cards.PersonId 
INNER JOIN 
    EAC.GroupPersonMap ON EAC.Person.Id = EAC.GroupPersonMap.PersonId 
INNER JOIN 
    EAC.[Group] ON EAC.GroupPersonMap.GroupId = EAC.[Group].Id
```

And the second one is

```
SELECT
    IsActive, ActivationDateUTC, ExpirationDateUTC, 
    Sitecode + '-' + Cardcode AS Credential, 'Badge' AS Type, 
    CASE 
       WHEN isActive = 0 
          THEN 'InActive' 
       WHEN ActivationDateUTC > GetUTCDate() 
          THEN 'Pending' 
       WHEN ExpirationDAteUTC < GetUTCDate() 
          THEN 'Expired' 
       ELSE 'Active' 
    END AS Status
FROM
    EAC.Credential
JOIN
    EAC.WiegandCredential ON Credential.ID = WiegandCredential.CredentialId
WHERE 
    PersonID = '32'
```

Where I would like to run the second query for each user of the first query using EAC.Person.Id instead of the '32'.

I would like all the data to be returned in one Dataset so I can use it in Report Builder.

I have been fighting with this all day and am hoping one of you smart guys can give me a hand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The field `PersonID` seems to come from the `EAC.Person` table. Is there a `PersonID` field in `EAC.WiegandCredential` or in `EAC.Credential`? Or maybe a `CredentialID` in the `Person` table?

Comment: No credentiaID in the persons table, EAC.WiegandCredential has PinCode],[CardCode],[SiteCode],[LastPrintedUTC],[CredentialId]. EAC.Credential has a PersonId. There are many records in the EAC.Credential table with a lot of duplicate PersonId;s I need the ones with the highest ID so i get the last inserted record from there. EAC.Credential has the fields [Id],[IsActive],[ActivationDateUTC],[ExpirationDateUTC],[ExternalId],[PersonId],[CustomerID],[ServerID]

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the only connection between the first dataset and the second is the `PersonID`, which exists in `EAC.Person` and `EAC.Credential`; but in `EAC.Credential`, the `PersonID` is duplicated, and you want the most recent entry according to the `ID` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description in the comments, I understand that the connection between the two datasets is actually the `PersonID` field, which exists in both `EAC.Credential` and `EAC.Person`; however, in `EAC.Credential`, duplicate values exist for `PersonID`, and you want only the most recent one for each `PersonID`.

There are a few ways to do this, and it will depend on the number of rows returned, the indexes, etc., but I think maybe you're looking for something like this...?

```
SELECT 
     EAC.Person.FirstName
    ,EAC.Person.Id
    ,EAC.Person.LastName
    ,EAC.Person.EmployeeId
    ,EAC.Person.IsDeleted
    ,Controller.Cards.SiteCode 
    ,Controller.Cards.CardCode
    ,Controller.Cards.ActivationDate
    ,Controller.Cards.ExpirationDate
    ,Controller.Cards.Status
    ,EAC.[Group].Name
    ,X.IsActive
    ,X.ActivationDateUTC
    ,X.ExpirationDateUTC
    ,X.Credential
    ,X.Type
    ,X.Status
FROM EAC.Person 
INNER JOIN Controller.Cards 
    ON EAC.Person.Id = Controller.Cards.PersonId 
INNER JOIN EAC.GroupPersonMap 
    ON EAC.Person.Id = EAC.GroupPersonMap.PersonId 
INNER JOIN EAC.[Group] 
    ON EAC.GroupPersonMap.GroupId = EAC.[Group].Id
CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
             IsActive
            ,ActivationDateUTC
            ,ExpirationDateUTC
            ,Sitecode + '-' + Cardcode AS Credential
            ,'Badge' AS Type
            ,'Status' = 
                CASE
                    WHEN isActive = 0
                        THEN 'InActive'
                    WHEN ActivationDateUTC > GETUTCDATE()
                        THEN 'Pending'
                    WHEN ExpirationDateUTC < GETUTCDATE()
                        THEN 'Expired'
                    ELSE 'Active'
                END 
        FROM EAC.Credential
        INNER JOIN EAC.WiegandCredential
            ON EAC.Credential.ID = EAC.WiegandCredential.CredentialId 
        WHERE EAC.Credential.PersonID = EAC.Person.PersonID
        ORDER BY EAC.Credential.ID DESC
    ) AS X
-- Optionally, you can also add conditions to return specific rows, i.e.:
-- WHERE EAC.Person.PersonID = 32
```

This option uses a `CROSS APPLY`, which means that every row of the first dataset will return additional values from the second dataset, based on the criteria that you described. In this `CROSS APPLY`, I'm joining the two datasets based on the fact that `PersonID` exists in both `EAC.Person` (in your first dataset) as well as in `EAC.Credential`. I then specify that I want only the `TOP 1` row for each `PersonID`, with an `ORDER BY` specifying that we want the most recent (highest) value of `ID` for each `PersonID`.

The `CROSS APPLY` is aliased as "X", so in your original `SELECT` you now have several values prefixed with the `X.` alias, which just means that you're taking these fields from the second query and attaching them to your original results.

`CROSS APPLY` requires that a matching entry exists in both subsets of data, much like an `INNER JOIN`, so you'll want to check and make sure that the relevant values exist and are returned correctly.

I think this is pretty close to the direction you're trying to go. If not, let me know and I'll update the answer. Good luck!

Comment: This is very close to what I need, however I am getting 5 duplicate results for each Person,  I checked my groups and have 5 groups so this is likely the cause. Any ideas?

Comment: Meaning each `PersonID` exists 5 times in the `EAC.Group` table?

Comment: I added DISTINCT and It seems to be working now, I wend from 155 results to 31 results. I think you guys figured it out. I am going to do some more testing and report back. Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries. `DISTINCT` can be a bit messy sometimes. If there is a logical reason behind the duplication, I just need to understand it and we can solve that, too.

Comment: The only cause that I can see is the 5 groups, It seems like the query runs through the groups and adds a result for each user regardless. I am not sure how to explain it but thats all I can think off

Comment: Where are these 5 groups actually listed?

Comment: On my report I am showing each group and the users that are in that group with all the other user related data. some users are in more than one group.

Comment: GroupPersonMap has the group Ids and the person Ids and the table Group has the group names

Comment: But not every person is listed 5 times, right? Can you maybe provide a fiddle for it ao I can see?

Comment: I am working through a remote connection. It is a mssql server and am working with a report builder. I am not sure how I can show you.

Comment: @LeenBalsters I confess that I am still a bit curious. Not having access to the schema or the data, I can only try to guess why each entry was duplicated 5 times. That sort of consistency typically comes from a bad `JOIN`, or occasionally an incomplete `WHERE` clause. If `DISTINCT` works for you, then fantastic; if not, let me know and we can work it out together. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
    select Query1.*, Query2.* from (
    SELECT 
        EAC.Person.FirstName, 
        EAC.Person.Id as PersonId,
        EAC.Person.LastName, 
        EAC.Person.EmployeeId, 
        EAC.Person.IsDeleted, 
        Controller.Cards.SiteCode, 
        Controller.Cards.CardCode, 
        Controller.Cards.ActivationDate, 
        Controller.Cards.ExpirationDate, 
        Controller.Cards.Status, 
        EAC.[Group].Name
    FROM         
        EAC.Person 
    INNER JOIN 
        Controller.Cards ON EAC.Person.Id = Controller.Cards.PersonId 
    INNER JOIN 
        EAC.GroupPersonMap ON EAC.Person.Id = EAC.GroupPersonMap.PersonId 
    INNER JOIN 
        EAC.[Group] ON EAC.GroupPersonMap.GroupId = EAC.[Group].Id) 
        Query1 inner join (SELECT top 100
        IsActive, ActivationDateUTC, ExpirationDateUTC, 
        Sitecode + '-' + Cardcode AS Credential, 'Badge' AS Type, 
        CASE 
           WHEN isActive = 0 
              THEN 'InActive' 
           WHEN ActivationDateUTC > GetUTCDate() 
              THEN 'Pending' 
           WHEN ExpirationDAteUTC < GetUTCDate() 
              THEN 'Expired' 
           ELSE 'Active' 
        END AS Status
    FROM
        EAC.Credential
    JOIN
        EAC.WiegandCredential ON Credential.ID = WiegandCredential.CredentialId
ORDER BY EAC.Credential.ID DESC) Query2 ON Query1.PersonId = Query2.PersonID
```

Just select two queries to join them like **Query1** and **Query2** by equaling PersonId data.

Comment: The OP mentioned in the comments that he only wants the most recent row for `PersonID` from `EAC.Credential`. Your approach will work, but you need to add a `TOP` clause.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, i updated my answer. But for most recent row "EAC.Credential" per Person, your solution is more better.

Comment: This works great just like the above Query, however here too i am getting 5 duplicate results for each user. I have 5 groups but not everybody is in all the groups.